# How do you make consistent effects on different clips in premier?

Tags: premiere, subtitles

I've got a method for making subtitles for videos. They need to grow onto the screen from small to big, then shrink again before the next line pops up. My way of doing this is setting keyframes in the effect controls, first small, then big, then big, then small. This achieves the effect nicely. The problem, however, is when I try to apply that effect to the rest of the subtitles (there are too many to do by hand). I copy it and paste attributes to the others, so they get the same keyframes. That mostly works, but it appears to calculate keyframe positions based on clip length so that the longer clips have slower effects. This is subtle, but noticable.

How do I make the words grow at a consistent rate? So all the subtitles would grow from 30% scale to 100% scale in a set number of frames, like 4?